# Rails-Simple Form and Devise current_user issue when using model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I am using Devise as my authentication system and simple form. I get a NoMethodError in Groups#show and an `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error. I use model associations to tie the groups and posts together. When I do `puts post.user.name` it correctly displays in my terminal but that line causes the above error and it's referencing Groups#show for some reason. Any thoughts?

Routes

```
resources :groups do
    resources :posts
end
```

Group Model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, presence: true  

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :attachments
end
```

Post Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, presence: true  
  validates :caption, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Group Controller

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    @group = current_user.groups.build
end

def create
    @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)
    @group.user_id = current_user.id
    if @group.save
        redirect_to groups_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

...
private

def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:group_name, :description, :user_id)
end

end
```

Posts Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]  
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3).order('created_at DESC')
    @post = current_user.posts.build
    @attachments = Attachment.all
end

...

def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @post.group_id = @group.id

    if @post.save
      redirect_to groups_path
    else
      render :new
    end
end
...
private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :user_id)
end

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def owned_post  
  unless current_user == @post.user
  redirect_to root_path
end

end  

end
```

groups/show.html.erb

```
<%= render "posts/index" %> 
...
```

posts/_index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'posts/form' %>
<%= render 'posts/posts' %>
...
```

posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([@group, @group.posts.build]) do |f| %>
...
```

posts/_posts.html.erb

```
<% @group.posts.each do |post| %>
<%= puts post.user.name %> ISSUE
<%#<%= render 'posts/post', post: post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It seems in some posts there are no user associated with that

Comment: I have <%= puts post.user_id %> as a test so when it is user_id it outputs the correct user_id in the terminal but when I do user_name it does not work properly. Could this be an issue when I do `@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)` in my Post create method and not properly chaining groups and posts?

Comment: Have you delete user manually ? and just try this post.try(:user).try(:name)

Comment: `<%= puts post.try(:user).try(:name) %>` outputs the correct username in the terminal. However, for some reason when I try to render that in my view it crashes and I get the error I mentioned above. I am not sure why this would be happening.

Comment: Then error not with posts maybe with some other statment

Comment: Any suggestions? I'm confused that it is correctly tied to the user id but for some reason, it isn't passing through these partials correctly?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: After asking on Reddit Rails, a generous user offered a solution that works. Apparently the `<%= simple_form_for([@group, @group.posts.build]) do |f| %>` creates a new post and adds it to the groups.posts array and so this causes issues when it iterates over _posts.html.erb and there is no user. More information can be found here: `https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/4lygix/unidentified_method_for_nil_class_devise_and/`

But replace the above simple_form line of code with `<%= simple_form_for([@group, Post.new(group: @group)]) do |f| %>` seemed to do the trick, as suggested by the generous user in the reddit link above.